# Why this code take more than 5 second if execute first time and when repeat takes less then 0.2s

Tags: python, python-3.x

I begin from a question:

Why first time execution is taking longer time then usual. Should I be worried about malware or similar?

I have code snippets below. I have pickled numpy ndarray in file. I tried to read all and generate total ndarray.

I registered a strange behavior.

Execution time takes more than 5s and only when I turn off Linux machine and I open terminal and i run first time this program.
Next program executions takes less then 0.2s.

Why first time execution is taking longer time then usual.
First I was thinking that it is a   extra time for **pycache**

I am running this code under venv and venv is activated via main.sh

read_pickle.py:

```
#!/home/****/bin/python3
# coding=utf-8

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time as t
from utilsC0 import read_pickle_from_file
from enums import *


def process(file):
    directory = "some localization" # external hdd
    path = directory + f"/{file}"
    arr = read_pickle_from_file(path)
    return arr


def f2():
    directory = "some localization" # external hdd
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, f))]

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p: 
        result = p.map(process, onlyfiles)

    result = np.vstack(result)

    print("End f2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = t.time()
    f2()
    t2 = t.time()
    print(f"{t2 - t1}")
```

And simple main.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source /home/***/bin/activate
python3 src/read_pickle.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Probably because all the files are loaded into the cache?

Shortly after the OS uses files, it is quicker for it to read them the next time. I would only expect this magnitude of difference if the files are very numerous or on a very slow external drive. Is that the case?

> 199 files with capacity 150,6 MB ... external HDD

Ah, that sounds very plausible. That would take many seconds to read the first time, and might then be stored in a cache which is very much faster. (See also @Jérôme Richard's comment pointing out that it is the sheer *number* of files that is probably the driver here.)

The cache is likely in the OS rather than in Python. As pointed out by @slothorp in the comments below, it could even be on the HDD.

#### No this does not signify malware

It is normal behaviour for computer systems to be designed to auto-detect what you are doing and be able to do it more efficiently next time, if possible. That is the main reason for cacheing.

Comment: I am reading 199 files with capacity  150,6 MB, Files are stored on external hdd. This is My Passport ultra (wester digital).

Comment: "The cache might be in the OS rather than in Python." - and it could even be in the HDD itself!

Comment: @luki The problem is not much the 150 MiB but the 199 files. Each access to a file from the file system generally requires multiple (quite random) fetches to the HDD. The thing is HDD have a very slow seek time: something like >10 ms. File systems like Ext3/Ext4 typically do 3 indirections/file, not to mention the directory needs to be fetched so to get the file inodes. In the end, this means several seconds. Note that the seek time tends to be lower with more IO request (since the spinning head can read >1 chunk per rotation cycle). Consider using a SSD for much faster performance.